# How to know the count of files on ftp folder?

Tags: ios, ftp

When my app starts I need to compare the count of files on ftp and the count of data in my CoreData entity. And if the count of files on ftp more then count of data in entity, application will start download.

How can I know the count of json-files on my ftp folder?

**EDIT**

This is the code of connection to ftp:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp:...json"]];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *error = nil;
if (!responseData) {
    return;
}

NSDictionary *ingredientsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (!ingredientsDictionary) {
    return;
}

//inserting to CoreData
```

Comment: By using FTP commands </cynicism>.  Ok, try to be more specific.  Show the code you have so far.  Don't say none, or this is not a real question.  How are you connecting to the server? -1

Comment: @borrrden see updated question and, please, cancel your downvote ))

Comment: You cannot get the list of the directory like this.  It requires opening a stream.  Apple has some sample code here -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

Comment: ooh, it's very difficult for the newbie like me (( is there any example of  function?

Comment: Everything you need is in ListController.m  In fact you can probably use it just the way it is.

Comment: I even don't know if this example works )) "Stream open error"... If it don't take a lot of your time, can you "compile" only needed functions from this example?

Comment: I don't know if it works either.  It depends on your server setup.  Most of that file is needed.  If you get an error, the you should make a new question with the *specific* error.  Stream open error is not enough, try to find a code or description.